# Removing numbers larger than 10 from a list in python

Tags: python, list

I cannot figure why some numbers greater than 10 are still left. Please help.
Thanks.

```
mylist = [12,31,2,5,45,12,45,4,32,1,6,8,5,31,12,11]

for num in mylist:
    if num >= 10:
        mylist.remove(num)

print(mylist)
```

Answer (score 1):

you are iterating a list that is being modified, so the iterator index skips to another thinking it's intact. I'd suggest another way for that goal

```
mylist = [number for number in mylist if number < 10]
```

Comment: This is not really equivalent as it is a rebinding, and not a mutation as attempted by the OP. Better do `mylist[:] = ...`.